# Laravel Session Expire Error Fix not logging out

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-cookies, csrf

So I have this error on a Laravel App where after a users session expires and they logout they are taken to a view with the following message `The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again`.  But refreshing does not fix the problem.

So after a lot of debugging and reading on the net I see that the reason for the error is because the `@csrf` `_token` on the destination page and the request' `XSRF-TOKEN` is not matching.  Therefore the user is left in a page 'refreshing' limbo.

My login form is a dropdown on the `welcome` blade and has the `@csrf` token set.

**Solution:**

To solve the problem I used [this] (https://github.com/mchekin/rpg/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php) neat trick to hack the problem.
This then lead to another error `view [auth.login] not found`.

To solve this there is a `showLoginForm` get route in the `LogginController` which I functionised as a redirect to the `/` of my app.

No more page expire problem, except the user is not logged out.  If I click the browser previous page arrow it takes me to the last viewed blade.

How can I nip this token problem in the hiney and logout at the same time?

Should I just use a normal php function of

```
if (isset($request)) {
   session_destroy($request);
}

// or
// set the following as except in VerifyCsrfToken class
protected $except = [
        'mysite/logout',
    ];
```

Comment: You have a bit of a saga going on here it seems! Rather than bypassing the issue, have you looked into why your tokens were mismatched? You haven't done something like turning on secure sessions / encypted cookies but are not using https to access your site?

Comment: @Spholt  A saga indeed!  The session config shows `secure` false, `encrypt` false and `http_only` true. The site has a verified SSL certificate.  The only thing that I can think of causing this, which I did not mention due to know thinking about it, is my navbar is an `@include`  with a dual login || logout form between `@guest` tags for the public and verified users.  So I thought maybe the `@csrf` that is set on the `@else` or verified side of the guest tag would cause  this problem due to token set and get difference but no this thought is not it.